# Could you use a synchrotron particle accelerator in a descending spiral pattern to create ion thrust for space travel?

Tags: space-travel, particle-accelerators, ions, synchrotron-radiation

Would it be theoretically possible to use a synchrotron particle accelerator that utilizes a spiral pattern to create ion thrust for space travel?

In this scenario, ions would be accelerated in a spiral path with a decreasing radius within the accelerator, and then expelled out of the accelerator at high speeds to generate thrust. The spiral pattern could potentially increase the efficiency of the acceleration process by increasing the radial confinement of the ions.

Comment: As far as I see, no. There are no spiral patterns and the accelerator is grounded because of the large number of components it is made of . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron#Principle_of_operation

Comment: Could particle accelerators benefit from utilizing the increasing centripetal acceleration that a particle would experience from the decreasing radius of the spiral pattern though?

Comment: here is no spiral pattern AFAIK.

Comment: As the particles go faster around a synchrotron, it takes more and more force to keep them in a stable orbit. Which is why the magnet fields has to be synchronised with the speed of the particles. In a cyclotron, the particles spiral _outwards_ as they speed up, as the magnetic field is constant. If you really wanted your particles to spiral _inwards_, you would need to spend a lot of energy to ramp up the magnets faster than the acceleration of the particles. Which would be wasteful and technically complicated if your aim is to get thrust out of your ions.